# skipping to specific currentTime with pixi-sound

Tags: audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api, pixi.js, current-time

I'm using pixi-sound.js and want to be able to skip to a specific point in the audio file. I've achieved this before using HTML5 audio by updating the currentTime, but I'm not sure where to access this with pixi-sound. There are at least two currentTime values, as well as 'progress', in the object, but changing those doesn't cause a skip.

```
var sound = PIXI.sound._sounds['track01'];
var currenttime = sound.media.context.audioContext.currentTime;
```

I would have thought this would be a common usage thing, but can't find any reference to it in the documents. Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In PixiJS Sound, you can hand over a `options` object as an argument for `play` method of an instance of `Sound` class. And the value of `options.start` is the "start time offset in seconds".

References: [@pixi/sound v4.2.0 source](https://github.com/pixijs/sound/blob/v4.2.0/src/Sound.ts#L72-L76), [pixi-sound v3.0.5 source](https://github.com/pixijs/sound/blob/v3.0.5/src/Sound.ts#L530)

---

In your code, if you want to play the sound from the point of 10 seconds offset, I think you can try like the following:

```js
var sound = PIXI.sound._sounds['track01'];
sound.play({ start: 10 }); // play from 10 seconds offset
```